# Exception "The requested operation requires elevation" when i run my .net code

Tags: c#, python-3.x, .net-core

"I'm trying to execute "main.py" file which is written in Python by my .net core web API but i got an exception.

I already give the permission of my Web API folder as well as my Python Code folder.

```
 var file = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DE.PythonPath");
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = file; 
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {                   
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            }
        }
```

I expect the python code run but it gives exception  "The requested operation requires elevation"

Comment: using (Process process = Process.Start(start))  this line giving the error

Comment: try to open visual studio as run as admin

Comment: Thanks @viveknuna it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio need to be run as admin. So run the Visual studio as Run as Administrator